# Как исправить значение поля

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Есть инпут в форме:

```
value="<?php echo esc_attr(get_user_meta($user->ID,'business_r_issue_date',true)) ?>"
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его дополнить условием:

Если значение **business_r_issue_date** пусто тогда по умолчанию значение будет строка "**не заполнено**", если нет, загружает данные **business_r_issue_date**

Спасибо.

Comment: Думается это нужно делать в функции get_user_meta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$userMetaValue = esc_attr(get_user_meta($user->ID,'business_r_issue_date',true));
$userVal = empty($userMetaValue) ? "не заполнено" : $userMetaValue;
?>
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $userVal ?>">
```